# ThreadX module size

Tags: module, threadx

assuming i've a ThreadX module flashed (or downloaded) is there a way to retrieve at run time from the Module Manager resident application the Module code and data size ?
Thank you in advance, best regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those values are in the preamble of the module.

Comment: Hi Scott, thank you for you answer! i had a look at the Module preamble here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/rtos/threadx-modules/chapter2  but i could not identify where the module code/data size are. Could you please point me where those info are in the preamble ?

Comment: They are there, about halfway into the preamble. Or look at struct here:https://github.com/azure-rtos/threadx/blob/d759e6bb9e040bc9f973ef706dc7b0a9c68be916/common_modules/inc/txm_module.h#L376

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i found the answer: in the C typedef description of module preamble (TXM_MODULE_PREAMBLE in txm_module.h) i've found:

ULONG   txm_module_preamble_code_size;    /* Module Instruction Area Size */
ULONG   txm_module_preamble_data_size;    /* Module Data Area Size        */